# C++20 function taking sequence of ints?

Tags: c++, c++20

Let's suppose we have an inline C++20 function `f`:

```
inline void f(size_t i, int x) { /*...*/ }
```

and we want to write another inline function `g` (or a multi-function overload set) that takes an ordered sequence of ints and for the ith one (zero-indexed) that has value `x`, calls `f(i,x)`

One way to do this would be:

```
void g(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        f(i, v[i]);
}
```

but this has several problems:

1. The caller may have the ints in contiguous runtime storage that is not in a `std::vector`, for example a `std::array`, built-in array.  Or the user may want to call the function with a subsequence of an existing `std::vector`, `std::array` or built-in array.  In such cases the caller needs to make an unnecessary heap allocation and copy.
2. A caller may know the number of ints as a constant expression.  This is lost by the `std::vector` solution.
3. A caller may have the ints themselves as constant expressions.  For example a caller may want to call `g` with a sequence of literal integers like `10,20,30`.

Is there a way to redesign `g` so that in all of the above cases `g` is both efficient and easy to use?

Can C++20 ranges help here?

What signature would you give `g` (or the multiple `g`s in an overload set) ?

Comment: C++17 - template function with a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for signature, and a implement with a [fold](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)?

Comment: @davidbak: doesn't work when the length of the sequence is not a constant expression.  Maybe as one member of the overload set of `g`?  But what would the others be?  And how would overload resolution work?

Comment: well, you said overload set.  use that above for #2 and #3 and use a span of some kind for #1?

Comment: @davidbak: Also what if the caller has the ints in a constexpr built-in array of int of 1000: `constexpr int A[1000] = /*...*/`.  The caller would have to write `f(A[0], A[1], /*...*/, A[999])`  with 1000 arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `span` is for:

```cpp
void g(std::span<int const> v) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        f(i, v[i]);
    }
}
```

This handles any kind of contiguous storage of integers, with no overload, and doesn't have to be a template.

If you really want to support arbitrary literals as well, you can add an overload that takes an `initializer_list` and forwards it:

```cpp
void g(std::initializer_list<int> i) {
    g(std::span(i));
}
```

Comment: How does the call of the span overload look when you have a `std::vector<int> v` to pass to it?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos `g(v);`

Comment: Ummm... which constructor is that calling? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot. constructor 7 is a forwarding reference, not a rvalue reference

Comment: Note that the algorithm being implemented works fine with non-contiguous ranges as well, so it seems unnecessary to me to constrain the interface to contiguous ones.

Answer (score 1):

> Can C++20 ranges help here?

It adds new options. But there are good pre-C++20 solutions as well. Here is one which works fine in C++11 (note that I gave a meaningful name to `g`):

```
template<class Range, class Fun, class Accumulator = std::size_t>
constexpr void
enumerate(const Range& r, const Fun& f, Accumulator acc = 0) {
    for (const auto& el : r) {
        f(acc++, el);
    }
}
```

> How would you call g in case 3

They could use one of

```
enumerate(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3}, f);
enumerate(std::array{1, 2, 3}, f);
```

Whether using C++20 or earlier, I wouldn't recommend the same function being callable as `g(1, 2, 3)` and `g(some_range)`. If you want to support the former, I would recommend providing it with another name (although templating `f` as I did in the example would make parameter pack inconvenient). See for example standard library and `std::max` vs `std::ranges::max_element`.

> And what about calling it with a subsequence of a std::vector ?

This is where C++20 brings useful features:

```
enumerate(std::ranges::subrange(first, last), f);
enumerate(v | std::ranges::drop(N) | std::ranges::take(M), f);
```

Pre-C++20 typical style is to instead provide a function accepting a pair of iterators rather than a range. For a consistent example, see for example `std::max_element`. Such function is slightly less convenient to use with complete ranges.

Comment: How would you call `g` in case 3, where you have the 3 integer literals `10,20,30`.  `g(10,20,30)` won't compile obviously, how would you call it?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos They could use `g(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3});` instead.

Comment: Ok, and what about calling it with a subsequence of a `std::vector` ?  Or a  `int* buf` and a runtime `size_t len` ?

Comment: If you add a `std::initializer_list<int>` overload, it becomes possible to do `g({1, 2, 3})` directly. Or you can even make it `std::initializer_list<T>` and perhaps constrain it so that `T` must be convertible to `int`. I don't think this will ever lead to ambiguity with the `Range&&` overload.